# How to add a heading in between checkout fields of WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I am customizing the WooCommerce checkout page fields. I want to add a heading (text) in between the fields. I have reordered the fields like this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ac_checkout_reorder_fields');

function ac_checkout_reorder_fields($fields) {

    $order = array(
        "billing_first_name", 
        "billing_last_name", 
        "billing_company", 
        "billing_email", 
        "billing_phone",
        "billing_address_1", 
        "billing_address_2", 
        "billing_postcode", 
        "billing_country" 
        

    );
    foreach($order as $field)
    {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
    }

    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;

}
```

Then I added a new heading like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_custom_heading' );

function add_custom_heading( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="add_custom_heading"><h2>' . __('Custom Heading Here') . '</h2></div>' ;


}
```

Now the fields are re-arranged and the custom heading is showing. But I want **the heading showing just below the name & company fields.** With my code, the field is being added below. How I an reposition this in my desired place.

PS: I also tried to add customize the sections of the entire field with this hook `woocommerce_checkout_fields` adding placeholder and removing the labels. Here are the codes but this also does not help me solve the issue.

```
function add_wc_custom_fields($fields) {
global $woocommerce;
    $countries_obj   = new WC_Countries();
    $countries   = $countries_obj->__get('countries');

     $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('First Name*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
           'class'    => array( 'form-row-first' ),
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('last Name*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
           'class'    => array( 'form-row-last' ),
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_company'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Company Name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-company')
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Address(Line 1)*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-addressL1')
        );
         $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Address(Line 2)*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('checkout-billing-addressL2')
        );
         $fields['billing']['billing_email'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Email Address*', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => array('form-row-first')
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_phone'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Phone Number', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('form-row-last')
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Town/City', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('form-row-first')
        );
        
$fields['billing']['billing_state'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('State/County', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('form-row-first')
        );
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'placeholder' => _x('Zip/Postcode', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('form-row-first')
        );
        $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
            'label' => '',
            'type' => 'select',
            'placeholder' => _x('Country', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
            'required' => false,
            'class' => array('form-row-last'),
              'options'    => $countries
        );
        return $fields;
    }

add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_wc_custom_fields');
```

Comment: it's hard to tell when all we can see is php codes...

Comment: My mistake. Here is the screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/rsTvwFh.png

Comment: Please note that since WooCommerce 3.0.4, a key 'priority' should be added to the fields in order to sort them:
`function ac_checkout_reorder_fields($fields) {
    $order = array(
        "billing_first_name", 
        ...
    );
    foreach($order as $i => $field)
    {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
        $ordered_fields[$field]['priority'] = $i;
    }

    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;
}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

we can use the filter `'woocommerce_form_field_' . $type`... where `$type` is the type of the input... in our case `billing_company` is of type text... this filter returns the html of the field, in our case billing field, `billing_company`.. the filter has 4 arguments being passed, these are `$field`, `$key`, `$args`, `$value`... we just need two of these...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_text','reigel_custom_heading', 10, 2 );
function reigel_custom_heading( $field, $key ){
    // will only execute if the field is billing_company and we are on the checkout page...
    if ( is_checkout() && ( $key == 'billing_company') ) {
        $field .= '<p class="form-row form-row-wide">Custom Heading</p>';
    }
    return $field;
}
```

**Important:** If we don’t format it as a paragraph with the class `form-row` it will be put to the top of all billing fields by Woocommerce (reasons unknown to me). This shows us that this as “Hack” and maybe your goals are achieved better differently.

Comment: This is awesome. I was really looking for that hook woocommerce_form_field. Thank you very much. This solves my problem and the answer is well accepted. Thanks man. :)

Comment: Can you suggest how to do this same thing, but to hook the heading in above the Account Username, and below the Billing Email fields? I tried `id="billing_email"` but it had no effect.

Comment: @inspirednz, I don't understand. Maybe you should create another question and add a screenshot. Also describe and include what you have tried so far in that question.

Comment: Thanks Reigel. I'll do that.

Comment: Posted new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049680/how-to-add-a-heading-above-woocommerce-account-fields-in-woocommerce

Comment: Seems not to work anymore... mujuonly solution's better.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hooking into an existing `woocommerce_form_field_<field_type>` filter such as `woocommerce_form_field_text`, I prefer to use the `woocommerce_form_field_<field_type>` filter to create a new field type. This allows us to add HTML output for an additional field type (and therefore we can use HTML output for a heading instead) and we can use this new heading "field type" when modifying checkout fields with the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter.

```
// Add field type to WooCommerce form field 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_heading','sc_woocommerce_form_field_heading', 10, 4 );
function sc_woocommerce_form_field_heading($field, $key, $args, $value) {
    $output = '<h3 class="form-row form-row-wide">'.__( $args['label'], 'woocommerce' ).'</h3>';
    echo $output;
}

// Modify checkout fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_heading_name'] = array(
        'type'      => 'heading',
        'label'     => 'Heading here',
    );
```

Using the above method the solution to the original question would be:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ac_checkout_reorder_fields');
function ac_checkout_reorder_fields($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_heading_name'] = array(
        'type'      => 'heading',
        'label'     => 'Heading here',
    );
    $order = array(
        "billing_first_name", 
        "billing_last_name", 
        "billing_heading_name",
        "billing_company", 
        "billing_email", 
        "billing_phone",
        "billing_address_1", 
        "billing_address_2", 
        "billing_postcode", 
        "billing_country" 
    );
    foreach($order as $field) {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
    }
    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field', 'addHeadingsInBetweenFormFields', 10, 4);

function addHeadingsInBetweenFormFields($field, $key, $args, $value = null) {

  if (is_checkout() & $key === 'billing_first_name') {
    $a = '<p class="form-row form-row-wide">Shipping</p>';
    return $a . $field;
  }
  return $field;

}
```

Comment: It’s important to understand that Woocommerce position fields that are not formatted inside a `<p>` tag always on top of the list. That’s why we have to imitate a normal form field. Don’t ask me why.