# How to add a heading above woocommerce-account-fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

### Preamble

My question is very similar to the one [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811301/how-to-add-a-heading-in-between-checkout-fields-of-woocommerce). The answer, I suspect, will also be very similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35811477/1092677).

### Scenario

The checkout page displays the typical Billing fields. Below those is the div class `woocommerce-account-fields`, in which is the div class `create-account`. The form nested in that has two fields, `account_username` and `account_password`.

I want to hook into this and display a heading below the last billing field (`billing_email`) and above the `account_username` field.

### What I tried

Reading the above mentioned question and answer, I figured I'd be able to do something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_text','XYZ_checkout_custom_heading', 10, 2 );

function XYZ_checkout_custom_heading( $field, $key ){
    if ( is_checkout() && ( $key == 'billing_email') ) {
        $field .= '<div id="add_custom_heading"><h3>' . __('MY CUSTOM HEADING') . '</h3></div>';
    }
    return $field;
}
```

But the result of this is no change to the page. However, if I use `key == 'account_username` it works, except obviously the heading ends up in the wrong place (below the account username field, and not above it).

Here is a screen shot of what I am referring to, visually.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, that location is above "create account" area.

If that's the case, you can use action hook `woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form','XYZ_checkout_custom_heading');

function XYZ_checkout_custom_heading( ){
    echo '<div id="add_custom_heading"><h3>' . __('MY CUSTOM HEADING') . '</h3></div>';
}
```

You can still use `woocommerce_form_field_text` but you should not use `$field .=  <heading>`. But instead, use `$field = <heading> . $field`. This way, your heading is added at the top. Not at the bottom. It's like `field + heading` when you're doing `$field .= <heading>` but `heading + field` with `$field = <heading> . $field`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_text','XYZ_checkout_custom_heading', 10, 2 );

function XYZ_checkout_custom_heading( $field, $key ){
    if ( is_checkout() && ( $key == 'account_username') ) {
        $field = '<div id="add_custom_heading"><h3>' . __('MY CUSTOM HEADING') . '</h3></div>' . $field;
    }
    return $field;
}
```

also note of `$key == 'account_username'`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the extra bit of information Reigel. That's good to know, and taught me something more about the PHP code I am messing around with! :-)

Comment: Does not work anymore, WooCommerce re-orders the fields and in the process of re-ordering them using JavaScript all the custom headings will com before all the fields.