# WooCommerce add heading at start of custom fields

Tags: woocommerce, field, heading

I have created custom fields in my WooCommerce checkout page billing form. It all works fine but I am trying to add an h3 element with text in between. So basically I ask for some additional information in the billing form, but I want to give that a heading.

I tried to create a h3 dynamically with Javascript/jQuery and insert before the specific id I want it to be. But this didn't work as I liked and I rather have a server-side solution.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the function where I define my custom fields. I've tried an echo at the beginning but it ends up displaying at the top of the entire form.

```html
// Modify billing fields

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);

    //echo '<h3>Wie is de verzender?</h3>';

    $fields['billing']['name_sender'] = array(
          'label' => __('Uw naam', 'woocommerce'),
          'required' => true,
          'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
          'clear' => true
    );
    $fields['billing']['email_sender'] = array(
          'label' => __('Uw email', 'woocommerce'),
          'required' => true,
          'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
          'clear' => true
    );
    $fields['billing']['phone_sender'] = array(
          'label' => __('Uw telefoonnummer', 'woocommerce'),
          'required' => true,
          'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
          'clear' => true
    );
    $fields['billing']['anoniem'] = array(
          'label' => __('Anoniem verzenden?', 'woocommerce'),
          'type' => 'checkbox',
          'class' => array('form-row-wide'),
          'clear' => true
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

A visual explanation:

[Visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzjbQ.jpg)

Comment: could you add some code?

Comment: Hi Cray, see the updated post. Thanks!

Comment: Check out this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811301/how-to-add-a-heading-in-between-checkout-fields-of-woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the `woocommerce_form_field_<field_type>` filter. This allows us to add HTML output for an additional field type (and in this case we can output HTML for a heading instead) and we can use this new heading "field type" when modifying checkout fields with the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter.

```
// Add field type to WooCommerce form field 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_heading','sc_woocommerce_form_field_heading', 10, 4 );
function sc_woocommerce_form_field_heading($field, $key, $args, $value) {
    $output = '<h3 class="form-row form-row-wide">'.__( $args['label'], 'woocommerce' ).'</h3>';
    echo $output;
}

// Modify checkout fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_heading_name'] = array(
        'type'      => 'heading',
        'label'     => 'Heading here',
    );
```

When modifying fields using the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter you can now place your new heading field in any position you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_woocommerce_form_field_radio( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Based on key
    if ( $key == 'radio_choice' ) {
        if ( ! empty( $args['options'] ) ) {
            
            $field = '<div><h1>Heading</h1><ul>';
            
            foreach ( $args['options'] as $option_key => $option_text ) {
                $field .= '<li>';
                $field .= '<input type="radio" value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '_' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" />';
                $field .= '<label>' . esc_html( $option_text ) . '</label>';
                $field .= '</li>';
            }
            
            $field .= '</ul></div>';
        }
    }
    
    return $field;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_radio', 'filter_woocommerce_form_field_radio', 10, 4 );
```