# WooCommerce - Conflict with new PayPal payments plugin and editing header at the start of custom fields in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

I have existing code that has been working fine with the former [WooCommerce PayPal Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/), but now that this has been abandoned in favour of a new version, [WooCommerce PayPal Payments](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/) I am getting a conflict with some custom code I am using to edit the headings of some custom fields I am using on the checkout page.

I used the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50519057/472501); ie:

```
// -- add heading type
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_heading','wpwp_checkout_fields_heading', 99, 4 );

function wpwp_checkout_fields_heading($field, $key, $args, $value) {
    $output = '<h3 class="form-row form-row-wide">'.__( $args['label'], 'woocommerce' ).'</h3>';
    echo $output;
}

// -- modify checkout fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wpwp_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );

function wpwp_checkout_fields($fields) {
    // add custom heading
    $fields['billing']['billing_email_heading'] = array(
        'type'      => 'heading',
        'label'     => 'Contact Information'
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_email_subscribe'] = array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'label'     => 'Keep me up to date on news and exclusive offers.',
        'required'     => false
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_address_heading'] = array(
        'type'      => 'heading',
        'label'     => 'Billing address'
    );

    // rename billing fields
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['label'] = 'Address';
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['label'] = 'City';

    // re-order billing fields
    $fields['billing']['billing_email_heading']['priority'] = 10;
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['priority'] = 20;
    $fields['billing']['billing_email_subscribe']['priority'] = 25;

    $fields['billing']['billing_address_heading']['priority'] = 29;
    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['priority'] = 30;
    $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['priority'] = 40;

    $fields['billing']['billing_company']['priority'] = 45;

    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['priority'] = 50;
    $fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['priority'] = 60;
    $fields['billing']['billing_city']['priority'] = 70;

    $fields['billing']['billing_country']['priority'] = 80;
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['priority'] = 90;
    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 100;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['priority'] = 110;

    // Change certain fields to optional
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] = false;

    // rename shipping fields
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']['label'] = 'Address';
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['label'] = 'City';

    // re-order shipping fields
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['priority'] = 20;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']['priority'] = 30;

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['priority'] = 35;

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']['priority'] = 40;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']['priority'] = 50;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['priority'] = 60;

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country']['priority'] = 70;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_state']['priority'] = 80;
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['priority'] = 90;

    // add heading to order notes
    $fields['order']['order_comments_heading'] = array(
        'type'      => 'heading',
        'label'     => 'Additional information'
    );

    // re-order order fields
    $fields['order']['order_comments_heading']['priority'] = 10;
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['priority'] = 20;

    return $fields;
}
```

But when I go to the checkout page I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of WooCommerce\PayPalCommerce\WcGateway\Settings\SettingsRenderer::render_multiselect() must be of the type string, null returned in **************/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/modules/ppcp-wc-gateway/src/Settings/SettingsRenderer.php:198

The code for this section is:

```
/**
 * Renders the multiselect field.
 *
 * @param string $field The current field HTML.
 * @param string $key   The current key.
 * @param array  $config The configuration array.
 * @param string $value The current value.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function render_multiselect( $field, $key, $config, $value ): string {

    if ( 'ppcp-multiselect' !== $config['type'] ) {
        return $field; // This is line 198
    }

    $options = array();
    foreach ( $config['options'] as $option_key => $option_value ) {
        $selected = ( in_array( $option_key, $value, true ) ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

        $options[] = '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' .
        esc_html( $option_value ) .
        '</option>';
    }

    $html = sprintf(
        '<select
                    multiple
                     class="%s"
                     name="%s"
                 >%s</select>',
        esc_attr( implode( ' ', isset( $config['input_class'] ) ? $config['input_class'] : array() ) ),
        esc_attr( $key ) . '[]',
        implode( '', $options )
    );

    return $html;
}
```

Line `198` is near the top of that code and I have inserted a comment denoting it.

In the below file from the new payment gateway plugin, which is located at `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce-paypal-payments\modules\ppcp-wc-gateway\src\WCGatewayModule.php` I have found the below, which may be relevant:

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_form_field',
    static function ( $field, $key, $args, $value ) use ( $container ) {
        $renderer = $container->get( 'wcgateway.settings.render' );
        /**
         * The Settings Renderer object.
         *
         * @var SettingsRenderer $renderer
         */
        $field = $renderer->render_multiselect( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_password( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_text_input( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_heading( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_table( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        return $field;
    },
    10,
    4
);
```

Is there any problems in my code that I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: It's a `null` but the function is saying it returns a `string`.  Make it not return null. Go back further and see why this is. Where is `render_multiselect()` called and passed the null value for `$field`? I mean you could just cast the null to an empty string but better to see why this happens and go from there.

Comment: Well my point is, isn't the problem coming from the PayPal payments code and not my code? Thing is, when I remove my custom filter I don't get this issue, so somehow my filter is conflicting with it and I don't know how.

Comment: Yes. That function signature annoys me. `render_multiselect(string $field, $key, $config, $value ): string` at least if you're going that route. Follow the trace and see where the function is passed a `null` for the `$field` argument.

Comment: Well, not finding that code on github but I do see the link you provided has a "review" section. Hilarious. Note the one star.

Comment: Yeah, the previous PayPal Gateway plugin also had pretty bad reviews, but I personally never had any issues with it. I did try the plugin by WebToffee, but had some issues with the button output on the checkout page.

The respective code above is in the `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/modules/ppcp-wc-gateway/src/Settings/SettingsRenderer.php` file.

I have also just updated my question with some new info on where I found a call to `render_multiselect`.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what I have done, but it appears the plugin is now broken and doesn't display correctly on the checkout page; it also manages to make other payment gateways not show as well. Tried reinstalling, but no fix. May have to revert to the WebToffee version and try and fix that. Thanks for looking into this anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears the solution is that you have to `return` the output from the function that is called from the call to the `woocommerce_form_field_heading` filter, instead of *echoing* it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_heading','wpwp_checkout_fields_heading', 99, 4 );
function wpwp_checkout_fields_heading($field, $key, $args, $value) {
    $output = '<h3 class="form-row form-row-wide">'.__( $args['label'], 'woocommerce' ).'</h3>';
    return $output;
}
```

It seems my call to the `woocommerce_form_field_heading` filter conflicted with the `render_multiselect` function call, which was called within the anonymous function listed above, in the call to the `woocommerce_form_field` filter:

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_form_field',
    static function ( $field, $key, $args, $value ) use ( $container ) {
        $renderer = $container->get( 'wcgateway.settings.render' );
        /**
         * The Settings Renderer object.
         *
         * @var SettingsRenderer $renderer
         */
        $field = $renderer->render_multiselect( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_password( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_text_input( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_heading( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        $field = $renderer->render_table( $field, $key, $args, $value );
        return $field;
    },
    10,
    4
);
```

I'm not entirely sure how they interact, but I'm assuming that `woocommerce_form_field_heading` gets called during calls to `woocommerce_form_field` and thus my `echo` statement interrupted the flow, and thus me *echo'ing* the data, instead of *returning* it, ended up with `null` being returned, and not a *string*, of which produced the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Renders the multiselect field.
     *
     * @param string $field The current field HTML.
     * @param string $key   The current key.
     * @param array  $config The configuration array.
     * @param string $value The current value.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function render_multiselect( $field, $key, $config, $value ): ?string
 {
    
        if ( 'ppcp-multiselect' !== $config['type'] ) {
            return $field; // This is line 198
        }
    
        $options = array();
        foreach ( $config['options'] as $option_key => $option_value ) {
            $selected = ( in_array( $option_key, $value, true ) ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    
            $options[] = '<option value="' . esc_attr( $option_key ) . '" ' . $selected . '>' .
            esc_html( $option_value ) .
            '</option>';
        }
    
        $html = sprintf(
            '<select
                        multiple
                         class="%s"
                         name="%s"
                     >%s</select>',
            esc_attr( implode( ' ', isset( $config['input_class'] ) ? $config['input_class'] : array() ) ),
            esc_attr( $key ) . '[]',
            implode( '', $options )
        );
    
        return $html;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some context here? Also, I cannot edit this code as it's from the plugin.

Comment: Require to edit a code in the plugin because conflict code with new version of plugin